# replace a line using bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file test.txt with line 3

```
start day = 29,
```

the day number, 29, needs to be updated daily. What is the easiest way to do it?

I tried

```
line3=" start day =  $(date +"%d"),"

sed -i "3c $line3" test.txt
```

the only problem is that the first space before "start" does not show up. the result is

```
start day = 29
```

rather than

```
start day = 29,
```

Comment: Why are you asking the exact same question 30 minutes apart?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape an initial space.

```
sed -i~ "3c\ start day = $(date +%d)," test.txt
```

should work.

(Note that this has rather little to do with bash, and everything to do with your `sed`.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, variable expansion happens before `c` command runs, so you are actually running sed like this

```
sed -i "3c  start..." test.txt
```

A backslash somewhere after `c` probably marks the start of the replacement text, so any whitespace after `\` is *not* ignored. In the absence of a backslash, I guess `sed` takes the first non-blank character as the start of the replacement text, so any whitespace before that is ignored.

So [sreservoir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16827191/1743811) is one way to go about it.

Alternatively, since you're just updating the dates, you can just replace the numbers (instead of entire line) so you don't have to worry about replicating other parts of the line.

```
sed -i "3s/[0-9][0-9]\?/$(date +%d)/" test.txt
```